# EJB injection not working in different classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jersey, ejb, jax-rs

I have tried to inject an Entity EJB(Facade and entity from MySQL database) but it doesn't work depending on the class it is in. I use a Rest webService and it work in the webService class.
I use a multi layered architecture and I don't want my EJB to be injected in this webService.

So, this is the @Stateless facade :

```
public class ActivityEntityFacade extends AbstractFacade<ActivityEntity> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistance")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public ActivityEntityFacade() {
    super(ActivityEntity.class);
}
```

}

this is the rest webService method working with EJB :

```
@EJB
private ActivityEntityFacade activityfacade;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{date}")
public List<ActivityEntity> activities(@PathParam("date") String date){
    List<ActivityEntity> activityList = activityfacade.findAll();
    return activityList;
}
```

And this is my activityManager which is supposed to work with the EJB and supposed to return this List to another layer :

```
public class ActivityManager implements Serializable, IActivity {

@EJB
private ActivityEntityFacade activityfacade;

public ActivityManager(){
}

public List<ActivityEntity> selectAll(){
    return  activityfacade.findAll();
}
```

}

This snipet return nullPointerException on the activityEntityFacade.
Have you any idea why it doesn't work in this case ?

EDIT:
the instance of activityManager is created in the previous layer:

```
 class ServActivityConsult implements IActivable{

@Override
public List<ActivityEntity> activityList() {
    IActivity managerActivity = new ActivityManager();
    return managerActivity.selectAll();
}

public ServActivityConsult(){
}
```

}

But the error come from return  activityfacade.findAll IN ActivityManager in our case.

Comment: How do you obtain an instance of ActivityManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an ActivityManager yourself, using `new ActivityManager()`. So the basic rules of Java apply: the constructor is called, and since it doesn't affect any value to `activityfacade`, this field is set to null.

For dependency injection to happen, you can't create the objects yourself, but get them from the container. So your class should look like

```
public class ServActivityConsult implements IActivable{

    @Inject
    private ActivityManager activityManager;

    @Override
    public List<ActivityEntity> activityList() {
        return activityManager.selectAll();
    }
}
```

And this class itself should be injected in a Jersey controller or an EJB.

Comment: I have tried to inject activityManager into ServActivityConsult with Inject and tried to inject ServActivityConsult into the webService class with EJB and I got the following error :                                              Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[Jersey REST Service]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.pdf.businessServices.activity.ServActivityConsult#com.pdf.businessServices.activity.ServActivityConsult not found

Comment: ServActivityConsult is not an EJB. So don't use `@EJB` to inject it. Use `@Inject`.